# Gnumake atomic rules using sentinel file failing

Tags: makefile, gnu, atomic, sentinel

I have been trying to use John Graham-Cumming's excellent article about "Atomic Rules in GNU Make"
at http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/atomic-rules-gnu-make?page=0%2C0

However, I sometimes have to specify a dependency between two files using a separate rule with no
recipe that looks simply like:

```
a : b
```

This has always worked as expected for me, but it fails miserably when specifying a dependency
between two atomic rules.  Here is a simple Makefile with 3 testcases:

```
atomic = $(eval $1: $(firstword $1).sentinel ; @:) \
         $(firstword $1).sentinel : $2 ; touch $$@ \
         $(foreach _, $1, $(if $(wildcard $_), , $(shell rm -f $(firstword $1).sentinel)))

d1 d2 d3:
    touch $@

## Test case 1 using sentinel and dependency (u1 u2 : t1 t2) specified in call to atomic
$(call atomic, t1 t2, d1)
    touch t1 t2

$(call atomic, u1 u2, t1 t2)
    touch u1 u2

## Test case 2 using sentinel and dependency (w1 w2 : v1 v2) specified as another rule does not work
$(call atomic, v1 v2, d2)
    touch v1 v2

$(call atomic, w1 w2, )
    touch w1 w2

w1 w2 : v1 v2

## Test case 3 showing that specifying a dependency (y1 : x1) with another rule does work
x1 : d3
    touch x1

y1 :
    touch y1

y1 : x1

##

clean :
    rm -f {d,t,u,v,w,x,y}{1,2,3}{,.sentinel} test{1,2,3}

test1 : u1
    touch test1

test2 : w1
    touch test2

test3 : y1
    touch test3
```

The first testcase does the right thing and builds everything in the expected order

```
> make test1
touch d1
touch t1.sentinel      
touch t1 t2
touch u1.sentinel      
touch u1 u2
touch test1
```

The second testcase fails miserably for atomic rules by building things in the wrong order

```
> make test2
touch w1.sentinel      
touch w1 w2
touch d2
touch v1.sentinel      
touch v1 v2
touch test2
```

The third simple testcase proves that using a separate rule to specify dependencies does work

```
> make test3
touch d3
touch x1
touch y1
touch test3
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?
Better yet, can anybody come up with a work-around so that test2 works the same as test1?
I'm really stuck.

Thanks,
-Tom

Answer (score 0):

You have your manually added dependencies on the wrong targets.

Recall what the atomic construct is doing. It is collapsing the set of original targets down to a single sentinel target and using that as a sequencing point.

You are adding your prerequisites to the individual original targets (the exact thing the atomic workaround was designed to allow/fix in the first place).

You need to add the prerequisites to the sentinel file: `w1.sentinel : v1 v2`

(Or better, use a sentinel function like in the original post and use `$(call sentinel,w1 w2): v1 v2`.

As an aside, be careful with adding spaces around <kbd>,</kbd> in make function calls. It can have very damaging and somewhat bizarre effects on things.

atomic.mk:

```
atomic = $(eval $1: $(firstword $1).sentinel ; @:) \
         $(firstword $1).sentinel : $2 ; touch $$@ \
         $(foreach _,$1,$(if $(wildcard $_),,$(shell rm -f $(firstword $1).sentinel)))

d1 d2 d3 d4:
>-------touch $@

## Test case 1 using sentinel and dependency (u1 u2 : t1 t2) specified in call to atomic
$(call atomic, t1 t2, d1)
>-------touch t1 t2

$(call atomic, u1 u2, t1 t2)
>-------touch u1 u2

## Test case 2 using sentinel and dependency (w1 w2 : v1 v2) specified as another rule does not work
$(call atomic, v1 v2, d2)
>-------touch v1 v2

$(call atomic, w1 w2, )
>-------touch w1 w2

w1 w2 : v1 v2

## Test case 4 using manual dependencies added to sentinel explicitly.
$(call atomic, z1 z2, d4)
>-------touch z1 z2

$(call atomic, a1 a2, )
>-------touch a1 a2

a1.sentinel : z1 z2

##

clean :
>-------rm -f {d,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,a}{1,2,3,4}{,.sentinel} test{1,2,3,4}

test1 : u1
>-------touch test1

test2 : w1
>-------touch test2

test4: a1
>-------touch test4
```

Output from `make -f ../atomic.mk -drR test1`:

```
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `../atomic.mk'...
Updating makefiles....
 ....
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `test1'.
 File `test1' does not exist.
  Considering target file `u1'.
   File `u1' does not exist.
    Considering target file `u1.sentinel'.
     File `u1.sentinel' does not exist.
      Considering target file `t1'.
       File `t1' does not exist.
        Considering target file `t1.sentinel'.
         File `t1.sentinel' does not exist.
          Considering target file `d1'.
           File `d1' does not exist.
           Finished prerequisites of target file `d1'.
          Must remake target `d1'.
touch d1
....
          Successfully remade target file `d1'.
         Finished prerequisites of target file `t1.sentinel'.
        Must remake target `t1.sentinel'.
touch t1.sentinel
....
touch t1 t2
....
        Successfully remade target file `t1.sentinel'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `t1'.
      Must remake target `t1'.
      Successfully remade target file `t1'.
      Considering target file `t2'.
        Pruning file `t1.sentinel'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `t2'.
       Prerequisite `t1.sentinel' is older than target `t2'.
      No need to remake target `t2'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `u1.sentinel'.
    Must remake target `u1.sentinel'.
touch u1.sentinel
....
touch u1 u2
....
    Successfully remade target file `u1.sentinel'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `u1'.
  Must remake target `u1'.
  Successfully remade target file `u1'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `test1'.
Must remake target `test1'.
touch test1
....
Successfully remade target file `test1'.
```

Output from `make -f ../atomic.mk -drR test2`:

```
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `../atomic.mk'...
Updating makefiles....
 ....
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `test2'.
 File `test2' does not exist.
  Considering target file `w1'.
   File `w1' does not exist.
    Considering target file `w1.sentinel'.
     File `w1.sentinel' does not exist.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `w1.sentinel'.
    Must remake target `w1.sentinel'.
touch w1.sentinel
....
touch w1 w2
....
    Successfully remade target file `w1.sentinel'.
    Considering target file `v1'.
     File `v1' does not exist.
      Considering target file `v1.sentinel'.
       File `v1.sentinel' does not exist.
        Considering target file `d2'.
         File `d2' does not exist.
         Finished prerequisites of target file `d2'.
        Must remake target `d2'.
touch d2
....
        Successfully remade target file `d2'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `v1.sentinel'.
      Must remake target `v1.sentinel'.
touch v1.sentinel
....
touch v1 v2
....
      Successfully remade target file `v1.sentinel'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `v1'.
    Must remake target `v1'.
    Successfully remade target file `v1'.
    Considering target file `v2'.
      Pruning file `v1.sentinel'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `v2'.
     Prerequisite `v1.sentinel' is older than target `v2'.
    No need to remake target `v2'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `w1'.
  Must remake target `w1'.
  Successfully remade target file `w1'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `test2'.
Must remake target `test2'.
touch test2
....
Successfully remade target file `test2'.
```

Output from `make -f ../atomic.mk -drR test4`:

```
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `../atomic.mk'...
Updating makefiles....
 ....
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `test4'.
 File `test4' does not exist.
  Considering target file `a1'.
   File `a1' does not exist.
    Considering target file `a1.sentinel'.
     File `a1.sentinel' does not exist.
      Considering target file `z1'.
       File `z1' does not exist.
        Considering target file `z1.sentinel'.
         File `z1.sentinel' does not exist.
          Considering target file `d4'.
           File `d4' does not exist.
           Finished prerequisites of target file `d4'.
          Must remake target `d4'.
touch d4
....
          Successfully remade target file `d4'.
         Finished prerequisites of target file `z1.sentinel'.
        Must remake target `z1.sentinel'.
touch z1.sentinel
....
touch z1 z2
....
        Successfully remade target file `z1.sentinel'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `z1'.
      Must remake target `z1'.
      Successfully remade target file `z1'.
      Considering target file `z2'.
        Pruning file `z1.sentinel'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `z2'.
       Prerequisite `z1.sentinel' is older than target `z2'.
      No need to remake target `z2'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `a1.sentinel'.
    Must remake target `a1.sentinel'.
touch a1.sentinel
....
touch a1 a2
....
    Successfully remade target file `a1.sentinel'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `a1'.
  Must remake target `a1'.
  Successfully remade target file `a1'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `test4'.
Must remake target `test4'.
touch test4
....
Successfully remade target file `test4'.
```

See [this graph](http://g.jk.gs/g7.png) to see the related prerequisite trees (manually created since I don't know of any good tools to do this from make output though I've wanted one for a while so apologies if I got something wrong).

Comment: Etan, thanks for your reponse!
Your suggestion of adding the prerequisites to the sentinel and not the actual targets does work.

However, what I find very strange is that the atomic methodology targets for a rule depend on the sentinel for THAT rule, and not the other way around.  For example, using John's example pretty much verbatim results in the following output:

    touch d1
    touch .sentinel.t1_t2  
    touch t1 t2
    touch .sentinel.u1_u2  
    touch u1 u2

Comment: You can see that the sentinel is created before the targets.  So, why doesn't simply adding a seperate dependency such as:

    u1 : t1

not behave just like :

    .sentinel.u1_u2 : t1

It certainly shouldn't flip the order of events completely around.

-Tom

Comment: The atomic call sets up a rule for the explicit targets depending on the sentinel target, which in turn depends on the original prereq targets. When you add a second manual prereq to the original targets it becomes a sibling prereq to the original sentinel target and then sequences as a sibling and not as a dependency. Looking at the `make -d` output from the various runs will be helpful here I think. I'll update my answer with it in a minute.